# How to find the maximum key in a 2d dictionary?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
D={'a':{'val1':1,'val2':5,'val3':4},
   'b':{'val1':4,'val2':2,'val3':7},
   'c':{'val1':2,'val2':4,'val3':9},
   'd':{'val1':5,'val2':6,'val3':3}}
```

Now I want to get the outer key, i.e., a,b,c or d which has the highest value of 'val2'. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [13]: max(D, key=lambda x: D[x]['val2'])
Out[13]: 'd'
```

[`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) can take any iterable as its first argument. `dicts` are iterables -- they iterate through their keys. 
So `max(D)` will return a key in D.

When you supply a `key` function such as

```
lambda x: D[x]['val2']
```

the function is called once for each value in the iterable (in this case, `x` takes on the values of the keys in `D`). The value returned by the function is used as a proxy for the key for the purpose of finding the max.

So `max` finds the key in `D` for which `D[x]['val2']` is the greatest.